# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: No such child: 15

Tags: java, swing

So I'm getting this kind of obscure error, and I don't know what it means. Without viewing my code, can someone tell me what causes this error and possible solutions to this error? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: No such child: 15
    at java.awt.Container.getComponent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.rectangleIsObscured(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.BufferStrategyPaintManager.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent._paintImmediately(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintImmediately(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$700(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Why "without viewing my code"? What state secrets does your code contain?

Comment: If your code is a trade secret, I'm afraid my answer will also be one.

Comment: Lol, the reason why I'm not showing the code is because it's kind of personal, and various information would be displayed which I'm not comfortable displaying to the public. The code is not a "secret" nor does it do anything that could be considered harmful. It's just a game that I've been working on for a while and I'm just curious to the causes of this error, and possible solutions.

Comment: @Josh: at the very least, don't show all your code (lord knows we don't want to see it, especially if it's long), but do show the code involved with the error. Otherwise you'll be forcing us to make uneducated guesses, or play 20 questions with you, a frustrating game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using swing use worker threads to control the components [worker thread tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html)

Comment: That's not a link to the tutorial but rather to the SwingWorker API.

Comment: whoops..wrong link :) ...well it was the first result on google any ways

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing any code, or any [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) which illustrates the issue we can basically only guess what is going on. My bet would be you are messing with your Swing components on another `Thread`, and the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` is a result of removing components on the wrong thread.

In order to debug this, I would start by using the [`CheckThreadViolationRepaintManager`](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/alexfromsun/archive/2006/02/debugging_swing.html) and fix any errors it indicates. 
If this does not work, I would try putting a breakpoint for the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, see which container causes the error and try to put breakpoints for any add and remove method on it to determine who removes the component causing the exception (probably on the wrong thread, which you can easily check with the `EventQueue.isDispatchThread()` method )

Comment: Oh I see. Well basically I have a JPanel, and I keep adding JProgressBars to it. Like I said earlier, this is a game and the progress bars are for the enemy's health bars, so whenever the healthbar gets to 0, i remove it from the jpanel because there's no need to have it in there anymore, and i just wanted to know a possible solution to this error

Comment: @JoshM if it is indeed a threading issue, you just have to remove the components on the Event Dispatch Thread and not just on any Thread (like for all Swing components, see [Swing concurrency tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more information about the EDT)

Comment: Uhmm, what do you mean by removing the components on the Event Dispatch Thread? Could you may give me an example please?

Comment: @Josh: you first! please show **some** of your involved code.

Comment: That's the thing though, I wouldn't know which section of the code to show, should I just show the main game thread? (The Thread where I'm actually removing the progress bars)

Comment: Ok so I think it'd be kind of irrelevant if I showed the whole thread because there's a lot of stuff that aren't relevant to my issue. I have this located inside the thread (It's inside a try block, you just can't see it): http://paste.strictfp.com/27502

Comment: Here is the method where I actually add the progress bar: http://paste.strictfp.com/27503 (this is not located inside the thread)

Comment: Any ideas? I know this may not be the reason why, but I'm adding components outside the Thread, but im removing them inside the Thread, I'm not sure if that's relevant or not but that's just my thought on this problem. If anybody else knows a solution, it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: @JoshM If you have created your own thread in which you start messing with Swing components it is most likely the cause of the issue. You can opt to use `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` to remove your components on the correct Thread.

Comment: I think I'm doing something wrong, I'm not sure what. Could you maybe show me on Teamviewer or something?

Comment: Here's what I added: http://paste.strictfp.com/27505  I put that inside my constructor

Comment: Oh I see what you mean, Okay I think I fixed it, thank you. :D